# Getting class data from BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am trying to get class data from an HTML page using BeautifulSoup.
Here is how the data looks like:

```
    <div class="quoteText">
      &ldquo;I'm selfish, impatient and a little insecure. I make mistakes, I am out of control and at times hard to handle. But if you can't handle me at my worst, then you sure as hell don't deserve me at my best.&rdquo;
  <br>  &#8213;
  <span class="authorOrTitle">
    Marilyn Monroe
  </span>
</div>
```

I just want the data under the class "quoteText" without the data in the class "authorOrTitle"

The following script returns the name of the author as well.

```
for div in soup.find('div', {'class': 'quoteText'}):
    print(div)
```

How can I get the "quoteText" class data without the "authorOrTitle" class data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

sample = """<div class="quoteText">
      &ldquo;I'm selfish, impatient and a little insecure. I make mistakes, I am out of control and at times hard to handle. But if you can't handle me at my worst, then you sure as hell don't deserve me at my best.&rdquo;
  <br>  &#8213;
  <span class="authorOrTitle">
    Marilyn Monroe
  </span>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(sample, "html.parser")

print(soup.find('div', {'class': 'quoteText'}).contents[0].strip())
```

Comment: The output I get is in the following format:

“
I
'
m
 
s
e
l
f
i
s
h
,
 
i
m
p
a
t


How to get it as a single list of characters?

Comment: My bad: I was using it inside the for loop and that's why it was returning each character in a separate row. I changed the function from find to findAll and everything's good now. Thanks!